# trouble running android ndk-build

Tags: macos, android-ndk, terminal, gnu-make

I am trying to create a build of google's tesserac library from github.

I am on a Mac Book Pro with android sdk, android ndk, Xcode, and eclipse installed. below is what i am doing in terminal and the error i am getting..  this is all greek to me.

```
    Last login: Mon Feb 11 11:57:51 on ttys000
BOSelidd196775:~ elidd1$ cd /Users/elidd1/Documents/libraries/Tesseract\ Optical\ Character\ Recognition/tess-two-master/tess-two 
BOSelidd196775:tess-two elidd1$ ndk-build
```

ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
    or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.
    BOSelidd196775:tess-two elidd1$

ok that problem was fixed, i didn't have xcode command line tools installed.. just xcode.  anyway, with that problem solved i am gett the following error:

```
Last login: Mon Feb 11 14:35:59 on ttys000
BOSelidd196775:tess-two elidd1$ cd /Users/elidd1/Documents/libraries/TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognition/tess-two-master/tess-two
BOSelidd196775:tess-two elidd1$ ndk-build
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-gcc: Command not found
make: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/i686-android-linux-gcc: Command not found
Compile thumb  : lept <= adaptmap.c
/bin/sh: /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/elidd1/Documents/libraries/TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognition/tess-two-master/tess-two/obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/src/src/adaptmap.o] Error 127
BOSelidd196775:tess-two elidd1$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output of 'ls /Users/elidd1/SDKS/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' ?
Sounds like either your ndk installation is incorrect or the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable is pointing to an incorrect location.

Answer (score 0):

my paths had not been set up properly in terminal